# Error when installing Netbeans

Tags: jdk

I need setup NetBeans on Ubuntu 12.04,but it got this error

[image]

Please help me. Thanks everybody

Comment: What jdk is installed in your system ?

Answer (score 1):

Install openjdk by:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

It installs several extra packages. After that netbeans find jdk automatically and normal installation completed smoothly...